# Setting Seed Project with Latest: Angular, Node/Express, Webpack, Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, webpack

I've been going over tutorials by [Maximilian](https://www.udemy.com/angular-2-and-nodejs-the-practical-guide/learn/v4/overview) on Udemy and I've hit a road block. I'm trying to setup a new project from scratch that's a node/express and angular 4 app. The problem, I think, is my script(s) in my `package.json`. I'm doing them exactly as the course suggests (course updated to Angular4 final); I'm trying to load the latest of all modules though.

**My setup commands**:

run express generator to generate shell and package.json

then

```
npm install @angular/common@next @angular/compiler@next @angular/compiler-cli@next @angular/core@next @angular/forms@next @angular/http@next @angular/platform-browser@next @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@next@angular/platform-server@next @angular/router@next @angular/animations@next --save

npm install --save zone.js rxjs core-js

npm install --save-dev @types/node @types/core-js

npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-merge angular2-template-loader awesome-typescript-loader del-cli html-loader typescript angular2-router-loader raw-loader
```

*Here's my code*:

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "movie-list",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "build": "del-cli public/js/app && webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch",
    "build:prod": "del-cli public/js/app && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress --profile --bail && del-cli 'public/js/app/**/*.js' 'public/js/app/**/*.js.map' '!public/js/app/bundle.js' '!public/js/app/*.chunk.js' 'assets/app/**/*.ngfactory.ts' 'assets/app/**/*.shim.ts' 'assets/app/**/*.ngsummary.json' 'assets/app/**/*.ngstyle.ts'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.2.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.0-rc.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "hbs": "~3.1.0",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "node-sass-middleware": "^0.11.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.41",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.22",
    "angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.3",
    "del-cli": "^1.0.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "typescript": "^2.3.3",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

***tsconfig.json***

```
{ 
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types"
        ],"lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ]
    }
}
```

***tsconfig.aot.json***

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "./public/js/app"
    },
    "typeRoots": [
        "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
        "es6",
        "dom"
    ],
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "skipMetadataEmit": true
    }
}
```

***webpack.config.prod.js***

```
var path = require('path');

var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.config.common.js');

module.exports = webpackMerge.smart(commonConfig, {
    entry: {
        'app': './assets/app/main.aot.ts'
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/public/js/app'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/js/app/',
        chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [
                    'awesome-typescript-loader',
                    'angular2-template-loader',
                    'angular-router-loader?aot=true'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: false
        })
    ]
});
```

***webpack.config.common.js***

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'app': './assets/app/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'html-loader' }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'raw-loader' }]
            }
        ],
        exprContextCritical: false

    }
};
```

When I run **`npm run build:prod`** I get the following error:

```
Error at C:/Users/Kenny/Dropbox/t/movie-list/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2075:38: Property 'keyFor' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
Error at C:/Users/Kenny/Dropbox/t/movie-list/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2079:37: Property 'match' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
Error at C:/Users/Kenny/Dropbox/t/movie-list/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2083:39: Property 'replace' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
Error at C:/Users/Kenny/Dropbox/t/movie-list/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2087:38: Property 'search' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
Error at C:/Users/Kenny/Dropbox/t/movie-list/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2091:39: Property 'species' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
Error at C:/Users/Kenny/Dropbox/t/movie-list/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2095:37: Property 'split' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
Error at C:/Users/Kenny/Dropbox/t/movie-list/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2099:43: Property 'toPrimitive' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
Error at C:/Users/Kenny/Dropbox/t/movie-list/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2103:43: Property 'toStringTag' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.
Error at C:/Users/Kenny/Dropbox/t/movie-list/node_modules/@types/core-js/index.d.ts:2107:43: Property 'unscopables' does not exist on type 'SymbolConstructor'.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build:prod"
npm ERR! node v7.9.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! movie-list@1.0.0 build:prod: `del-cli public/js/app && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress --profile --bail
&& del-cli 'public/js/app/**/*.js' 'public/js/app/**/*.js.map' '!public/js/app/bundle.js' '!public/js/app/*.chunk.js' 'assets/app/**/*.ngfactory.ts' 'assets/app/**/*.shim.ts' 'assets/app
/**/*.ngsummary.json' 'assets/app/**/*.ngstyle.ts'`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the movie-list@1.0.0 build:prod script 'del-cli public/js/app && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progr
ess --profile --bail && del-cli 'public/js/app/**/*.js' 'public/js/app/**/*.js.map' '!public/js/app/bundle.js' '!public/js/app/*.chunk.js' 'assets/app/**/*.ngfactory.ts' 'assets/app/**/*.
shim.ts' 'assets/app/**/*.ngsummary.json' 'assets/app/**/*.ngstyle.ts''.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the movie-list package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     del-cli public/js/app && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress --profile --bail && del-cli 'public/js/app
/**/*.js' 'public/js/app/**/*.js.map' '!public/js/app/bundle.js' '!public/js/app/*.chunk.js' 'assets/app/**/*.ngfactory.ts' 'assets/app/**/*.shim.ts' 'assets/app/**/*.ngsummary.json' 'ass
ets/app/**/*.ngstyle.ts'
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs movie-list
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls movie-list
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Kenny\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-05-28T17_02_43_104Z-debug.log
```

I have scowered the web in search of practical means of putting together the latest Angular and Node/Express using webpack along with typescript. I've tried changing `core-js` to an earlier release. I cannot find much information on putting it all together.

My goal is to be able to be able to use `npm run build` for development (which works strangely, I'll post `webpack.config.dev.js` below) and use `npm run build:prod` for production (cleaning up files, generating my `bundle.js`).

***webpack.config.dev.js***

```
var path = require('path');

var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.config.common.js');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/public/js/app'),
        publicPath: '/js/app/',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/js/app/',
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [
                    {loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader', options: {
                        transpileOnly: true
                    }},
                    {loader: 'angular2-template-loader'},
                    {loader: 'angular2-router-loader'}
                ]
            }
        ]

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:
`"target": "es5"`
to:
`"target": "es6"`
in both files